# Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath returns different result after publishing the website

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my development machine, Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath returns expected results. e.g ~/Inventory/Home.aspx. It gives the same results when I COPY the website to the server (using Visual Studio Copy Website Option).

However, results are differnt when I PUBLISH the website to the server.

If this is the norm, what is the way to acheive the same results even after publishing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I deployed the website in Default Website folder as an application. After removing it to the root of IIS (Sites folder), the problem was resolved.